# Recyclerview item click not always work and sometimes can work but with more more click (don't know how many click)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onitemclick

`Recyclerview` item click not always work and sometimes can work but with more more click (don't know how many click).If just click once that can't clicked.

**Note** few days ago I tried to click once and it's worked, but now when I tried to running again using AS it's not work, even though I not modified that file

My code

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapterRiwayat extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterRiwayat.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    private static final String TAG = RecyclerViewAdapterRiwayat.class.getSimpleName();

    List<GetDataAdapterRiwayat> getDataAdapter;

    ImageLoader imageLoader1;
    String FIXURL = "http://192.168.1.101/AndroidFileUpload/";
    String url = FIXURL + "uploads/";
    String StatusRiwayat;


    public RecyclerViewAdapterRiwayat(List<GetDataAdapterRiwayat> getDataAdapter, Context context) {

        super();
        this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items_riwayat, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Viewholder, int position) {

        final GetDataAdapterRiwayat getDataAdapter1 = getDataAdapter.get(position);

        imageLoader1 = ServerImageParseAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

        imageLoader1.get(url+getDataAdapter1.getFotoSetelahRiwayat(),
                ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                        Viewholder.networkImageView,//Server Image
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,//Before loading server image the default showing image.
                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert //Error image if requested image dose not found on server.
                )
        );
        Viewholder.networkImageView.setImageUrl(url+getDataAdapter1.getFotoSetelahRiwayat(), imageLoader1);


        Viewholder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "coba nih5 : "+getDataAdapter1.getNamaJalanRiwayat());

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailRiwayatActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return getDataAdapter.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView ImageTitleNameView;
        public NetworkImageView networkImageView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            ImageTitleNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item_riwayat);

            networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VollyNetworkImageView2);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: did u got any solution ?

Answer (score 3):

If you only have the issue after scrolling / flinging the RecyclerView, it's a known bug in the SupportLibrary

> After a user scrolls, they cannot click on an item in a RecyclerView. (AOSP issue 66996774)

Issuetracker ID [66996774](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66996774) and also [69823266](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69823266) because it's still not fixed in 27.0.1. Even though Google states [it has fixed it](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#27-0-1).

Most important: the fix here (by Chris Banes, Googler) works perfectly: https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/8391b5adb9ee42180893300850ed02f2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            public TextView ImageTitleNameView;
            public NetworkImageView networkImageView;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

                super(itemView);
                ImageTitleNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item_riwayat);

                networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VollyNetworkImageView2);


                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getLayoutPosition(); // use this to get item from list
                    Log.d(TAG, "coba nih5 : "+getDataAdapter1.getNamaJalanRiwayat());

                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailRiwayatActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: still same. must with more click then can clicked

Answer (score 0):

**Your code**

```
Viewholder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "coba nih5 : "+getDataAdapter1.getNamaJalanRiwayat());

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailRiwayatActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

creating new listener every time to the itemView , Instead implement OnClickListener or pass **null** before assigning new Listener

```
 Viewholder.itemView.setOnClickListener(null);
Viewholder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "coba nih5 : "+getDataAdapter1.getNamaJalanRiwayat());

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailRiwayatActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Or add listener in `ViewHolder` `onCreateViewHolder()`

```
v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(); // use this to get item from list
                    Log.d(TAG, "coba nih5 : "+getDataAdapter1.getNamaJalanRiwayat());

                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailRiwayatActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Comment: first way is not working.. and the second way get error `cannot resolve method getLayoutPosition()`

Comment: put that code in `onCreateViewHolder` right? it's same error `cannot resolve method getAdapterPosition`

Comment: sorry I forgot to add, getAdapterPosition() method of view holder, So use its object to call

Answer (score 0):

Add these to your parent element of R.layout.recyclerview_items_riwayat

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to child views of item layout (Not root element only childs!!) (R.layout.recyclerview_items_riwayat):

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

Answer (score -1):

That's probably due to the parent's `onTouch` method which intercepts the touch event. You need to check if there is a parent view like `SwipeLayout`.